# Why can't I pass AngularJS's $location.search() as a callback?

Tags: angularjs

I have something like:

```
function x(hash, f) {
    Object.keys(hash).forEach(key => {
        f(key, hash[key]);
    });
}
```

There's more to it but that's the part that fails.

I can call it like:

```
x(h, function(n, v) { $location.search(n,v) });
```

but when I try to simplify to

```
x(h, $location.search);
```

it blows up in `x`

> ```
> angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property '$$search' of undefined
>     at search (angular.js:13337)
>     at x (parameters.js:120)
> ```

If I step through in the debugger, `f` looks like a function as I enter `x`.  Is there a way around this or do I need that ugly wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call is failing because the `this` context is `undefined`.
The `search` function expects to be bound to the `$location` object.

The call can simplified to:

```
x(h, $location.search.bind($location));
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/iNlINbT7KJLJ9fCUf4lu?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.